# Where does the "newline" (\n) come from? (pattern matching using "flex")

Tags: apache-flex, newline, design-patterns, matching

**I have an experimental flex source file(lex.l):**

```
%option noyywrap
%{
  int chars = 0;
  int words = 0;
  int lines = 0;
%}
delim     [ \t\n]
ws        {delim}+
letter    [A-Za-z]
digit     [0-9]
id        {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
number    {digit}+(.{digit}+)?(E[+-]?{digit}+)?
```

%%

{letter}+ { words++; chars += strlen(yytext); printf("Word\n"); }
\n        { chars++; lines++; printf("Line\n"); }
.         { chars++; printf("SomethingElse\n"); }

%%

int main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
  if(argc > 1)
  {
    if(!(yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
    {
      perror(argv[1]);
      return (1);
    }
  }

yylex();

printf("lines: %8d\nwords: %8d\nchars: %8d\n", lines, words, chars);
}

**I created an input file called "input.txt" with "red apple" written in it. Command line:**

```
$ flex lex.l
$ cc lex.yy.c
$ ./a.out < input.txt
Word
SomethingElse
Word
Line
lines:        1
words:        2
chars:       10
```

**Since there is no newline character in the input file, why the "\n" in lex.l is pattern matched? (The "lines" is supposed to be 0, and the "chars" is supposed to be 9)**

**(I am using OS X.)**

**Thanks for your time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very possible that your text editor has automatically inserted a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: I tried to use: `$ echo "red apple" > input.txt`, and got the same result. (I assume that **echo** would not insert a newline at the end of the file.)

Comment: Thank you @jprete! Problem solved! I tried to use: `$ echo -n "red apple" > input.txt`, and got the expected result. (**echo** with **-n** option would not output the trailing newline)

Comment: Exactly. As a side point, it's often convenient to have a newline at the end of all files, so it might be a good idea for you to consider that an acceptable condition.